# Two questions on the James $p$-space $J_{p}(1<p<\infty)$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$. The James $p$-space $J_{p}$ is the Banach space of all sequences of real numbers $(a_{i})_{i}\in c_{0}$ such that 
$$\|(a_{i})_{i}\|=\sup\{(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{p_{j-1}}-a_{p_{j}}|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}:p_{0}<p_{1}<\cdots<p_{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}\}<\infty.$$
Let $(e_{n})_{n}$ be the unit vector basis of $J_{p}$ and $(e^{*}_{n})_{n}$ be the sequence of biorthogonal functionals. It is known that $(e_{n})_{n}$ is a shrinking monotone basis for $J_{p}$. I have the following two questions:

Question 1: Let $z^{*}_{n}=\sum_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}c_{i}e^{*}_{i}$ be a semi-normalized block basic sequence in $J^{*}_{p}$ and suppose that $\sum_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}c_{i}=0$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is the sequence $(z^{*}_{n})_{n}$ equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{p}$?

Question 1 is true for $p=2$ as proved by Alfred Andrew in Israel J. Math.(1981).

Question 2: Is the dual $J_{p}^{*}$ of $J_{p}$ weakly sequentially complete?

Thank you!

Comment: Q 1: Doesn't Andrew's proof show that $z_n^*$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_q$, where $q$ is the conjugate index to $p$?

Comment: Q 2: It is elementary that a weakly sequentially complete space that has separable dual is reflexive.

Comment: Q 1:  I am not sure that Andrew's proof can be used to show that $(z^{*}_{n})_{n}$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{q}$. I have to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this question should be considered as answered, following the  comments of Bill Johnson as:

(1) One can follow the argument of Andrew and show that $z_n^*$ is equivalent  to the unit  vector  basis  of  $\ell _q$, where     $q$  is conjugate  to $p$.

(2)    The   well-known result of  Rosenthal implies that each bounded sequence either contains a  weakly Cauchy  subsequence  or a subsequence equivalent to the  unit vector  basis  of  $\ell_ 1$  Hence, by the Eberlein-Smulian theorem,  if  the space is weakly complete,  it should either contain $\ell_1$ or be reflexive.   (See Lindenstrauss and    Tzafriri,  vol. 1, page    99  for   Rosenthal's theorem.)